# Can we create AI and Opengl based games in php?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, flash, opengl

Hi I am new learner and want to set my carrier as web game developer, As i know there are too many languages with we can create online games like : Javascript, jQuery, Adobe Flash, Unity 3D.

But all these languages are not server side and flash have no good jobs.

My question with server side languages :

Can we create games in PHP, Ruby, NodeJs or C# ? Maybe java is sure for answer but problem with server too.

I searched for hosting and Runy have 1.9 Support and PHP Mostly 5.3.

Suggest me which language i can use for OpenGl Games Development Online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you should choose unity3d or flash because it's good for online games development that you are looking for :) But sorry for language you specified. You can do with that but i think not that type you are looking for:.

Comment: Can we use backend language like PHP or Ruby With That Languages ?

Comment: yes you can if you are familiar with some javascript then you can easily learn flash action script. Here is one basic tutorial with php and action script but you should learn first and as your question i think you don't know Action script or javascript.

Visit : http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/webmaster/projects/article.php/3876786/Flash-Tutorial-for-Web-Developers-Create-a-Flash--PHP-Based-Discussion-Forum.htm